# jQuery each + FileReader not returning correct values

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, filereader

I'm trying to read 2 CSV files which contains rows of numbers each.

```
<input type="file" id="file[0]" name="file[0]">
<input type="file" id="file[1]" name="file[1]">
```

File 1 content:

```
111
222
```

File 2 content:

```
333
444
```

After reading the contents, I push the numbers to new array (csv_arr) and count the occurrences (csv_cnt).

```
var csv_arr = new Array();
var csv_cnt = 0;

$("[id^=file]").each(function(index) {
    file = $(this)[0].files[0];

    if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var csv_val = e.target.result.split("\r\n");

            for (var i = 0; i < csv_val.length; i++) {
                csv_arr.push( csv_val[i] );
                csv_cnt++;
            }
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
});

console.log(csv_arr);
console.log(csv_arr.length);
console.log(csv_cnt);
```

The result of the console.log are:

```
['111','222','333','444']
0
0
```

As you can see from the result, the array looks ok, but then the array length and count are 0! I'm stuck and not sure what is really wrong. Any idea?

Comment: ...just out of curiosity, why don't you use a single `input` element with `multiple` attribute?

Comment: Actually each file input has further dropdown to identify which files belong to which product. Thus I need to separate the file input.

Answer (score 1):

Your code *works* beside you forgot that `filereader` is **asyncronous**.
That means that your console.logs will trigger while the `onload` is still loading data.

And no. your Array, (at least with the exact code you posted) **cannot result in what you said** - Otherwise you'd get the `4` and `4` since the Array has values. That means that you're getting this instead:

```
[]
0
0
```

Pass the console.logs into the `onload` function and you'll get this:

```
["111", "222"]
2
2
["111", "222", "333", "444"]
4
4
```

Comment: I need to use the 'csv_arr' and 'csv_cnt' for subsequent processing. So is there a way to store the values after each + filereader finished?